# android custom scroll view with ad at bottom

Tags: java, android, layout

I have an internal custom view set up and that part seems to be working perfectly - what i'm wondering is ... is it possible to limit the height of the custom view similar to something along the lines of in Swing where you have a Scroll Pane in the Center of a Border Layout and another Panel in the South of the Border Layout.

I have 4 text views in the north, then my custom scroll view in the center, and i'd like to have the app remain static at the bottom

I tried doing the following 3 in the xml: (pseudo xml - most deleted for readability)

1.

```
<LinearLayout ...> // vertical
    <TextView ...></TextView>
    <LinearLayout ...> // horizontal
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView...>
        <LinearLayout ...>
            <view class="blah.blah.blah.CustomView" ...>
            </view>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout ...>
        <com.google.ads.AdView ... />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

2.

```
<LinearLayout ...> // vertical
    <TextView ...></TextView>
    <LinearLayout ...> // horizontal
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView...>
        <LinearLayout ...>
            <view class="blah.blah.blah.CustomView" ...>
            </view>
            <RelativeLayout ...>
                <com.google.ads.AdView ... />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

3.

```
<LinearLayout ...> // vertical
    <TextView ...></TextView>
    <LinearLayout ...> // horizontal
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
        <TextView ...></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView...>
        <LinearLayout ...>
            <view class="blah.blah.blah.CustomView" ...>
            </view>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout ...>
    <com.google.ads.AdView .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

any help as to what i can do to make this work would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, try #1 using weight=1 and a 0dip height on your `ScrollView`:

```
android:layout_height="0dip"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:fillViewport="true"
```

Your ScrollView will automatically grow to fill up the remainder screen, pushing the ad (`RelativeLayout`) to the bottom (on any screen size/orientation).

Although its not your exact layout, here's a full sample from one of my layouts which should be similar.

[image: Portrait]

[image: Landscape]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_name_label"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Name"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_name_edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                android:capitalize="sentences" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_type_label"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Type"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_type_edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                android:capitalize="sentences" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edit_description_label"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:text="Description"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dip" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edit_description_edittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                android:capitalize="sentences" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingRight="3dip"
        android:paddingLeft="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_background">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_cancelbutton"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dip"
            android:paddingRight="20dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_savebutton"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="30dip"
            android:paddingRight="30dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try doing this the scroll view completely disappears - i also tried the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380383/how-to-get-ad-to-show-at-bottom-of-screen-without-overlap and saw the same thing happen, not quite sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  Its hard to say without seeing the whole layout, so I've included a real layout that works for me.  The Save/Cancel bar is pinned to the bottom (regardless of screen size / orientation) because the ScrollView always expands to the full size it has available (even if the content inside is short, thanks to android:fillViewport="true").