# Banner bottom Android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How can i set banner on bottom of the screen ?
I tried with RelativeLayout and it stay bottom, but outside screen.

That's my simple code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_home"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background" 
   android:orientation="vertical">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background2" 
            android:orientation="vertical">

          ......
       </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
         ....
       </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

I have set android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" but not change

Comment: What do you mean by "outside screen"?

Comment: I think, we need to set the height and width of the banner , depends upon the device resolution.

Comment: @enfix Please See my answer and if answer is helping you then please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below XMl Code for Display Banner in Bottom Part.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_home"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background">

       <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/layout_body"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background2" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_above="@+id/layout_banner">

          ......
       </LinearLayout>
       <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_banner"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
         ....
       </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your banner inside the `RelativeLayout` and use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`
Check the solution in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5380447/1434631

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `LinearLayout` with id `layout_body` is already occupying the whole screen. So the `RelativeLayout` with id `layout_banner` have no where to go but outside the bottom of the screen.

Instead, you may try the following:

1. Change the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`
2. Change `layout_body` and `layout_banner`'s `layout_height` to `warp_content`
3. Add `layout_weight="1"` to `layout_body`

This should archive your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your view in a linear layout, you can add an empty view which is filling the gap with the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` like :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_home"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background" 
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

      ......
   </LinearLayout>
   <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
   <AnyLayout (you choose)
        android:id="@+id/layout_banner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     ....
   </AnyLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can set the whole inside a RelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/layout_home"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/background">

   <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout_body"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/login" 
        android:orientation="vertical">

      ......
   </LinearLayout>
   <AnyLayout (you choose)
        android:id="@+id/layout_banner"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     ....
   </AnyLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```